# What does it mean when you put elements under (or inside) a React component?

Tags: reactjs

A React component in general seems to be just a function that return an HTML element, or a class with the `render` function that can do that.

So let's say the component is called `About`.

If the code is just `<About />`, then that means here, render the HTML, according to the states it is tied to.

But what about:

```
<About>
  <SomethingElse />
  <YetAnother>
    <SomeMore />
  </YetAnother>
</About>
```

What does that translate to?

Answer (score 2):

The content

```
<SomethingElse />
<YetAnother>
  <SomeMore />
</YetAnother>
```

will become a special prop of `<About />`, called [children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx)

The structure will be called recursively and the compiled JSX becomes several `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)`

But note that React won't do anything for your children by default, if your About component only contains

```
class Abount extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>About</h1>
  }
}
```

and doesn't render `this.props.children` at all, then

```
<SomethingElse />
<YetAnother>
  <SomeMore />
</YetAnother>
```

will simply be ignored.

So if you want to support nested components in your components, you will need to handle `props.children` by yourself.

The simplest way is to write `{this.props.children}` in your render function, for example:

```
class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>About</h1>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Nicely explained :) I think a lot of people assume child components work by magic in React, rather than just being another prop.

Comment: By the way, it seems that the way `About` has a bunch of children, is just like an HTML tag `<body> ... </body>` has a lot of children.  So, in HTML format, it is like "enclosing everything inside of `body`", but if you draw the HTML tree, then it is one `body` element node, and then a bunch of children which are the children of that node

Answer (score 0):

Consider the follwoing code

```
<About>
  <SomethingElse />
  <YetAnother>
    <SomeMore />
  </YetAnother>
</About>
```

Here You have nested components. So `SomethingElse, YetAnother` are rendered as  children inside the `About` component. If you see the rendering code of the `About` component, you will find something like `{this.props.children}` which basically means that the children components of the `current` component will be rendered here.

Similar is the case with `YetAnother` which has `SomeMore` as the child component.

I hope, I was able to explain it.

Comment: it seems that you have to explicitly use the line `{this.props.children}` in your `About` component's code to render the children? If you don't include that line, then no children will be displayed at all?

Comment: Yes, if your dont't include the line `this.props.children` then no children will be rendered